# Method required a bean of type "..." that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm following the REST tutorial [here](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/).

With the following code I get this error `Parameter 0 of method initDatabase in com.example.demo.LoadDatabase required a bean of type 'com.example.demo.EmployeeRepository' that could not be found.`

LoadDatabase.java:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class LoadDatabase {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoadDatabase.class);

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner initDatabase(EmployeeRepository repository) {

        return args -> {
            log.info("Preloading " + repository.save(new Employee("Bilbo Baggins", "burglar")));
            log.info("Preloading " + repository.save(new Employee("Frodo Baggins", "thief")));
        };
    }
}
```

EmployeeRepository.java:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {

}
```

DemoApplication.java:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.13</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Employee.java:

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.Objects;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
class Employee {

    private @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;
    private String name;
    private String role;

    Employee() {}

    Employee(String name, String role) {

        this.name = name;
        this.role = role;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return this.role;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {

        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Employee))
            return false;
        Employee employee = (Employee) o;
        return Objects.equals(this.id, employee.id) && Objects.equals(this.name, employee.name)
                && Objects.equals(this.role, employee.role);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(this.id, this.name, this.role);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee{" + "id=" + this.id + ", name='" + this.name + '\'' + ", role='" + this.role + '\'' + '}';
    }
}
```

Does this mean it doesn't find `repository`? What am I doing wrong? I'm clueless because I'm following the tutorial and it doesn't mention it.

Full OUTPUT LOG:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-17.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true -Dmanagement.endpoints.jmx.exposure.include=* -javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=55473:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Users/alexanderclaes/Downloads/demo/target/classes:/Users/alexanderclaes/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/3.1.1/spring-boot-starter-3.1.1.jar:/Users/alexanderclaes/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/3.1.1/spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:/Users/alexanderclaes/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/3.1.1/spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.1.1.jar:/Users/alexanderclaes/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/3.1.1/spring-boot-starter-logging-3.1.1.jar:/Users/alexanderclaes/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.4.8/logback-classic-1.4.8.jar:/Users/alexanderclaes/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.4.8/logback-core-1.4.8.jar:/Users/alexanderclaes/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-to-slf4j/2.20.0/log4j-to-slf4j-2.20.0.jar:/Users/alexanderclaes/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.20.0/log4j-api-2.20.0.jar:/Users/alexanderclaes/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/2.0.7/jul-to-slf4j-2.0.7.jar:/Users/alexanderclaes/.m2/repository/jakarta/annotation/jakarta.annotation-api/2.1.1/jakarta.annotation-api-2.1.1.jar:/Users/alexanderclaes/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/6.0.10/spring-core-6.0.10.jar:/Users/alexanderclaes/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jcl/6.0.10/spring-jcl-6.0.10.jar:/Users/alexanderclaes/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.33/snakeyaml-1.33.jar:/Users/alexanderclaes/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/3.1.2/spring-data-jpa-3.1.2.jar:/Users/alexanderclaes/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/3.1.1/spring-data-commons-3.1.1.jar:/Users/alexanderclaes/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/6.0.10/spring-orm-6.0.10.jar:/Users/alexanderclaes/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/6.0.10/spring-jdbc-6.0.10.jar:/Users/alexanderclaes/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/6.0.10/spring-context-6.0.10.jar:/Users/alexanderclaes/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/6.0.10/spring-expression-6.0.10.jar:/Users/alexanderclaes/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/6.0.10/spring-aop-6.0.10.jar:/Users/alexanderclaes/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/6.0.10/spring-tx-6.0.10.jar:/Users/alexanderclaes/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/6.0.10/spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:/Users/alexanderclaes/.m2/repository/org/antlr/antlr4-runtime/4.10.1/antlr4-runtime-4.10.1.jar:/Users/alexanderclaes/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/2.0.7/slf4j-api-2.0.7.jar:/Users/alexanderclaes/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/persistence/javax.persistence/2.2.1/javax.persistence-2.2.1.jar com.example.demo.DemoApplication

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.1.1)

2023-07-17T10:06:05.878+02:00  INFO 91212 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication using Java 17.0.7 with PID 91212 (/Users/alexanderclaes/Downloads/demo/target/classes started by alexanderclaes in /Users/alexanderclaes/Downloads/demo)
2023-07-17T10:06:05.880+02:00  INFO 91212 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-07-17T10:06:06.057+02:00  WARN 91212 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'initDatabase' defined in class path resource [com/example/demo/LoadDatabase.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'initDatabase' parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.demo.EmployeeRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
2023-07-17T10:06:06.060+02:00  INFO 91212 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-07-17T10:06:06.072+02:00 ERROR 91212 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method initDatabase in com.example.demo.LoadDatabase required a bean of type 'com.example.demo.EmployeeRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.demo.EmployeeRepository' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: This means that the `EmployeeRepository` could not be created. Is there anything else on the stacktrace or on logs that could help troubleshoot why the `repository` could not be instantiated?

Comment: @spyrospal Following link provides the full output log: https://pastebin.com/QaKccLr0

Comment: @Alexander "This page is no longer available". Please include the relevant part of the log in the question.

Comment: @Jorn apoligies, I included it in my question to make sure it's there.

Comment: `javax.persistence-2.2.1.jar` is your problem. You included JavaEE dependencies while using Spring Boot 3.1 which is JakartaEE. If you are using EclipseLink (instead of hibernate) upgrade to a version of EclipseLink that is JakartaEE compatible and make sure your entities are using `jakarta.persistence` instead of `javax.persistence` imports (which they probably are now).

Comment: Your `EmployeeRepository` is an interface. Is this supposed to work? Don't you need a class that can be instantiated? Or shouldn't EmployeeRepository be annotated as a Bean?

Comment: @f1sh the problem is the parameter `repository` right? It says do it like this in the tutorial but it's literally non-existent as far as I can see. But I don't know how the `initDatabase` gets called or where it gets called so I'm a bit clueless

Comment: Where is your main class (which includes the line `public static void main(String[] args)` in the file)?

Comment: @Jesse I added `DemoApplication.java` to the question, thanks for helping

Comment: Repeating the problem is `javax.persistence-2.2.1.jar` as you are following a tutorial but decided to use newer versions of the framework. The guide is for Spring Boot 2.7 not 3.x. SO either downgrade your Spring Boot version and follow the tutorial or upgrade and remove the `javax.persistence-2.2.1.jar` dependency and fix the imports to `jakarta.persistence`.

Comment: @M.Deinum I'm getting the same error still and am also getting something in the class where I had to update the import `Class 'Employee' should have [public, protected] no-arg constructor`

Comment: @M.Deinum I managed to update that package successfully, but I'm still getting the error from the question above.

Comment: I tested it in Spring Boot 2.6.1 and it works. @M.Deinum may be right - you can downgrade your Spring Boot version to 2.7 or below. I haven't tested it with 3.1.1, so I can't reproduce your problem myself.

Comment: I'll downgrade and keep you posted, thanks for helpign out

Comment: If you are still not successful, you can post your`pom.xml` and `Employee.java` files to display more details.

Comment: Now I'm getting: `/Users/alexanderclaes/Downloads/demo/src/main/java/com/example/demo/EmployeeRepository.java:5`
java: cannot access org.springframework.data.repository.ListCrudRepository
  class file for org.springframework.data.repository.ListCrudRepository not found

Comment: Remove `javax.persistence`, remove `spring-dat-jpa`. Add `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` instead. You are using an incompatible Spring Data version (which is for Spring Boot 3 and ideally you should be using the starter so you get the appropriate compatible versions). You are trying to outsmart the dependency management that is already being handled for you.

Comment: If you want to upgrade the Spring Boot 3 the only thing you need to change is the imports in your entity from `javax.persistence` to `jakarta.persistence` (after changing the Spring Boot version).

Answer (score 0):

Below is the `pom.xml` file that I tested successfully before:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

If you want to test it on Spring Boot version 2.7.1 you can copy&paste it after backup your original `pom.xml`.

Answer (score -4):

```
@Repository
```

public interface EmployeeRepository {
}
？ok

Comment: Spring Data interfaces don't need `@Repository`, they are detected otherwise.

Comment: You need to provide fuller, formatted code and explain your answer -- as well as checking that it is correct.